# Cant dowload google app engine 1.9.1

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

So I am trying to run a google web application through eclipse, but when I run it gives me an error to please check for newest SDK version, which is 1.9.1. And sure enough Im working with 1.9.0, but I cant find any updates for GAE and it says all components are installed under help->install new software.

Ive tried downloading .zip file of 1.9.1 and extracting it to my eclipse\dropins dir but that doesnt do anything either. What do I do after Ive extracted it in to my dropins dir? And why cant I find the new version using eclipse own installation tool? Should I really be getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Eclipse Help -> Check for Updates instead.  Sometimes the SDK detects a new version before Eclipse does, and everything synchronizes within a day or so.  The SDK message is informational, not an error, so you can safely ignore it in the meantime.

Comment: Some time before midday UTC on Friday 21st March 2014 the 1.9.1 SDK became available in Eclipse -> Check for Updates.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Martin suggested, you can download the SDK separately and unzip that in any separate folder. Then from your Eclipse Preferences, go to Google, App Engine SDK and select that particular version folder.

FYI - I prefer keeping the SDK versions separate from Eclipse. That way, I have the entire list of SDKs available in another folder structure and can use it across Eclipse versions too.